# /usr/bin/X :0 -audit process

Tags: linux, process

Hello I am trying to solve some internet problems that I have.
It is a university computer and I do not have root access. I want to understand what is this processor, that root has started, and if you think it can be related to my slow internet connection.

[image]

Comment: Copy-paste instead of taking a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `X` process is the [X server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_server#Software_architecture). That's the part of the operating system that communicates with the display and input hardware and provides windows to applications. It's the low-level part of the GUI.

The many `X` lines show different threads of the same process (you can guess that they're the same process because they all have exactly the same memory figures). You have one X process, which is to be expected on a computer with a GUI console. The process has racked quite a few hours, which is normal if you've been displaying stuff on it for a while.

The existence of this process has absolutely nothing to do with network connections or their perceived slownes.